# Change default population string for form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, field

I'm building a form on ROR4, using the simple_form gem, to modify my user's data. The thing is that my database is normalized to have the user's first and last name in lower case. So I have the following in my User model:

```
before_save :lowercase_names

def lowercase_names
  self.first_name.downcase!
  self.last_name.downcase!
end
```

But of course when I populate my upadate form with the user object I get the following:

```
First name: carlos
Last name: ledezma
```

I was wondering if there is a way to override this behavior so Rails would print instead:

```
First name: Carlos
Last name: Ledezma
```

That is, the titleized version of the fields.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form set the value to titleized name

```
=f.input :first_name, :value => @user.first_name.titleize
```

The above line will vary depending on if you are using simple form or not. But it will give you the basic idea. You are overwriting the value of the input field

If you want it to be changed everywhere, then override getter for first_name and last_name

```
def last_name
  self.read_attribute(:last_name).titleize
end

def first_name
  self.read_attribute(:first_name).titleize
end
```

Be aware that this will titleize your first name and last name everywhere you call the getter

Comment: This works fine, but is there a way to make it a general solution? (without putting it in a partial). I mean, that every time the field gets called, it's string representation will be titleized

Comment: You could override the getter for first_name and last_name. Changed my answer

Comment: I corrected your syntax, because simple_form doesn't have a `:value` option, one must use the `input_html` to change the value of the field

Answer (score 0):

Try using the value attribute of the `text_field` helper in your form to set the shown value as the capitalized first and last name:

```
<%= f.input :first_name, :value => f.object.first_name.capitalize %>
<%= f.input :last_name,  :value => f.object.last_name.capitalize %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated

Also, you can override getter method in `User` model like:

```
def first_name
  self.read_attribute(:first_name).capitalize
end

def last_name
  self.read_attribute(:last_name).capitalize
end
```

Comment: This actually generates an infinite recursion, because `self.first_name` will just call again the getter.